# Core Data not saved after App Relaunch

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, concurrency, persistence

I am using the parent/child contexts paradigm in my app. The parent context is a MainQueueConcurrencyType. I am using a Private QueueConcurrencyType as a child to save my newly acquired data (which I get from rss feeds). I save everything in the private context's thread using performBlockAndWait, like suggested. Everything seems to be working fine. My NSFetchedResultsController's context is set on the parent main context, and its delegate methods get called every time I save which means the private context merges the changes with the main context perfectly. I even added this piece of code to check if it was indeed merging, and it did…

```
        let workerContext = CoreDataStack.newPrivateQueueContext()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, object: workerContext, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (notification) -> Void in
        println("                                       MERGING")
        CoreDataStack.defaultMainQueueContext().mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
    }
```

So everything seems fine, my data is loading in my tableview as it gets updated. BUT!! when I reload my app, it seems no data was persisted. My table view is empty, my fetch request returns zero object. It seems I have to go through the whole process again. Does anyone have any idea why that would be ?

Comment: Do you save the *main* context?

Comment: Doesn't the line "CoreDataStack.defaultMainQueueContext().mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)" save the main context?

Comment: Wow you are right… I though the mergeChangesFromContext method saved the context. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: Add it as an answer so I can accept it